# PHP: Call function inside preg_replace

Tags: php, function, preg-replace

The below code responsible for bbcode tags in dle script. "\1" is the link which i would like to call with function, but instead I'm getting plain text

```
        $txt = preg_replace( "#<!--dle_video_begin:(.+?)-->(.+?)<!--dle_video_end-->#is", '[video=\\1]', $txt );
```

my function

```
function videoD ($str) {
        if (strpos($str,'http://') !== false) {
                $vid = uppod_encode($str);
                echo (uppod_encode($str));

        } else {
                $vid = uppod_decode($str);
                echo (uppod_encode($vid));
        }
}
```

what i've tried:

```
$txt = preg_replace( "#<!--dle_video_begin:(.+?)-->(.+?)<!--dle_video_end-->#is", '[video=videoD(\\1)]', $txt );


$txt = preg_replace( "#<!--dle_video_begin:(.+?)-->(.+?)<!--dle_video_end-->#is", '[video=videoD(1)]', $txt );

$txt = preg_replace( "#<!--dle_video_begin:(.+?)-->(.+?)<!--dle_video_end-->#is", '[video=\\videoD(1)]', $txt );
```

Comment: use the `e` modifier, or use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_calback).

Comment: @cbuckley - preg_replace_callback, yes. But the `e` modifier should be avoided.

Comment: @Spudley couldn't agree more; not sure why I even suggested it ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$txt = preg_replace_callback('#<!--dle_video_begin:(.+?)-->(.+?)<!--dle_video_end-->#is', function($matches){
    return "[video=videoD({$matches[1]})]";
}, $txt);
```

Comment: i'm getting the output of:  [video=videoD(link)]

Comment: @Crazy_Bash I'm using the first capture group like in your examples. Use $matches[2] if you need the second one. Or var_dump($matches) in the callback to see how it looks and pick the one you need.